# max_iter hyper parameter in sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

What is the significance of max_iter in sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans? Is this the maximum number of times partial_fit() can be executed on batches of data?

Comment: I think when we train MiniBatchKMeans model using partial_fit() in incremental manner, max_iter doesn't really have any significance.

Answer (score 1):

> max_iterint, default=100
>
> *Maximum number of iterations over the complete dataset before stopping independently of any early stopping criterion heuristics.*

**It's the number of iteration over the full dataset.**

Number of *partial_fit* will depend on batch_size

> batch_sizeint, default=100
>
> *Size of the mini batches.*

> partial_fit(self, X[, y, sample_weight])
>
> *Update k means estimate on a single mini-batch X.*

Ref :

[User guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mini-batch-k-means)

[Class Def.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn-cluster-minibatchkmeans)